# CSS 3 animation pausing (so to speak)

Tags: animation, css

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to pause (or put adjust the timing of an event at a certain point) a CSS3 animation?

Lets say I had a circle that bounced, and I wanted it to take 2 seconds to reach its highest point, and either pause (or put a long time) it at its highest point, then depending if it is paused/frozen or on a long interveral have it return to its original positition. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pause and resume CSS3 animation using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript)

Comment: There's not a way to do this without using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Animation Keyframes may solve your problem.

```
.whatever{
     -webkit-animation: bouncepause 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bouncepause {
        0% {
                bottom:0;
        }
        5% {
                bottom:200px;
        }
        95% {
                bottom:200px;
        }
        100% {
                bottom:0;
        }
}
```

I included only `-webkit-` vendor prefixes to keep it simple.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Hcs/)