# Pause and change current frame of CSS3 animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

It's possible to change current frame of CSS3 animation after pause it (using jQuery or Vanilla JS)? How can I do that?

More specifically, I'm thinking about slidebar which I can change current frame...

Answer (score 0):

Šime Vidas write a nice post on [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript)
But there is still problem with CSS3 on old IE.
And working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/TnGhH/2/

```
.pause{
     -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
    -o-animation-play-state:paused; 
    animation-play-state:paused;
}
```