# CSS animation: pausing

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a simple CSS3 animation which I would like to pause on hover.

Here is a simplified version:

```
h1 {
    animation-name: test 3000ms infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes test {
    from {
        transform: translate(0,0);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(100px,0);
    }
}
h1:hover {
    animation: paused;
}
```

It works, but pausing means jumping back to the `0%` state. Is there a way to either (a) pause in the current state of (b) resetting more gracefully, such as running through one final loop?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause and resume CSS3 animation using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript)

Comment: @magreenberg Completely unrelated. (a) it’s not asking how to pause it, which is already happening and (b) I certainly don’t need a JavaScript solution which is easy, but unhelpful. I’m looking for how _not_ to suddenly reset the state when pausing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`animation-play-state`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp)** as below:

```
h1 {
    animation-name: test;
    animation-duration:3000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-play-state:running;/*running normally*/
}

h1:hover {
    animation-play-state:paused; /*paused when hover*/
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fvq6gkyr/)**

> **Note -  The `animation-play-state` property is not supported in *Internet Explorer 9* and *earlier versions.***

Comment: That’s it. I didn’t even notice that one. That will be very useful. Note: neither animation nor transition work in _Internet Exploiter 9_, so nothing lost there … Thanks

Comment: Cool.. Happy Coding.. :)