# How to pause a Spinkit animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I'm using a loading indicator from [Spinkit](https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit.git), specifically the circle indicator, but I didn't figure how to pause the animation, so the circle can be still on the screen without spinning.

The CSS is [this](https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit/blob/master/css/spinners/8-circle.css). Following an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript), I tried to toggle this class on click using jQuery:

```
.paused{
  -webkit-animation-play-state:paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state:paused;
  -o-animation-play-state:paused;
  animation-play-state:paused;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.sk-circle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('paused')
  })
})
```

```css
.sk-circle {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
@keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.paused {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sk-circle">
  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
</div>
```

But the animation didn't pause and the circles kept on spinning. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code did not work is because you are adding the **paused** class to `.sk-circle` when it is clicked but the **animation is actually present on the** `.sk-child` **element's pseudo.**

So, modify the jQuery code such that the class is added on the `.sk-child` element and then in CSS set the `animation-play-state: paused` under `.sk-circle .sk-child.paused:before`. This would set the paused play state to the animation. (*The selector has to be more specific because the one that is adding the animation has a specificity of 021.*)

<sup>**Note:** I've removed the browser prefixes in the below snippet and included prefix-free library to keep it small.</sup>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sk-circle').on('click', function() {
    $('.sk-circle .sk-child').toggleClass('paused');
  });
});
```

```css
.sk-circle {
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}
@keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
.sk-circle .sk-child.paused:before {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sk-circle">
  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
</div>
```