# How to toggle HTML/CSS animation on hover and on click

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am having trouble trying to stop and start animation whenever I hover over the element or on click. This is my HTML element:

```
<div class='marquee'>
   <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marquee {
    width: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

Right now, the animation just goes on forever by default. How can I have it so that whenever I **hover** over or **click** on the `h1` or the `div`, the animation will pause and resume accordingly. I'm assuming to pause/restart the animation on click, I would need a JavaScript function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pause and resume CSS3 animation using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript)

Comment: @OmriAttiya I'm not using webkit so I don't think that'll solve it

Comment: @Mr.ZZ I'm not using a <marquee> tag since it became obsolete

Comment: @RedApple you don't need the webkit prefixes anymore, but that's still the same, JS `style.animationPlayState` and CSS  `animation-play-state`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `animation-play-state` rule:

```css
.marquee {
    width: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee h1:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<div class='marquee'>
   <h1>Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

Or with JS:

```js
function stopAnimation(e){
   if (e.target.style.animationPlayState == ""){
     e.target.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
   } else {
     e.target.style.animationPlayState = "";
   }
}
```

```css
.marquee {
    width: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marquee h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 15s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

```html
<div class='marquee'>
   <h1 onclick="stopAnimation(event)">Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked for hover! Thank you! I was wondering how to do this for onClick as well.

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: Hi, So I'm using React so the div and the h1 are returned by a React component so I can't use "this" for the "stopAnimation(this)" for the onClick since that "this" would point to the whole React Component rather than just the h1.

Comment: On react the event is passed as deafult. you can use ` e.target` to get the element

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. Whenever my mouse leaves, it just resumes animation.

Comment: It works now. I removed "event" from ```onClick={this.stopAnimation}```. Thank you!

Comment: Not related to the question but I was wondering if you would know how to achieve this: once the animation is paused, I want to scroll through the text to reach the end, only on paused tho, on resume, there would be just the animation and no scroll.

Comment: That would be something different, and more JS code would be used. I imagine you are thinkhing in a drag event

Comment: You can post it with a separate question. and putting some your code in react

Comment: Hi, I just posted a new question for that. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using jquery to change the animation property.

```
$('.marquee').mouseenter(() => { $(this).css("animation: marquee 15s linear infinite"); } );

$('.marquee').mouseleave(() => { $(this).css("animation: none"); } );
```