# Pausing animation on the web

Tags: javascript, animation

I recently watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=09V_JAGTs2E&feature=emb_logo
Which really inspired me about animation. But it is many steps to essentially get
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause
So my question is how prevalent is Animation.pause? When can it be expected in spec? Are there alternatives? I noticed on stack overflow there were solutions for pausing css animations, but they essentially started the animation over when they were finished. So yes it paused the animation, but on restart it still had the 5 second animation restarted, when you paused at say 2 seconds. So the remainder ended up being a 7 second animation. Not really a pause, but a restart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pause and resume CSS3 animation using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804444/how-to-pause-and-resume-css3-animation-using-javascript)

Comment: I saw that post too, the example was very difficult to pause to test if it fixed the issue. But it seems like a solution. What about the Animation.pause call, is that viable too?